# Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier

Tags: spring, spring-batch

how can i resolve these issue i tried all possible ways struck at these point
Parameter 1 of method simpleJobLauncher in com.cpa.be.batch.config.SchedulingConfigurer required a single bean, but 2 were found

Comment: Hi @VenuKannuri, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question as is looks like it won´t attract much attention to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have @Bean used more than once for a SchedulingConfigurer object, creating two beans. Using @Autowired in this case would not know which one to choose.